# Return a value from forEach in protractor - Managing closures

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, jasmine, protractor

I have the following helper code from which I am trying to return the number of occurences of a string.

```
this.getActualFilteredStatusCount = function(strFilter){
    return this.getTotalRows().then(function(count){
        var totalCount = count;
        var statusElementsObjs = $$(CommonElements.filterElement);
        var occurence = 0;
        var index = 0;
         $$(CommonElements.filterElement).each(function(item){
            return item.getText().then(function(input){
                ++index;
                    if (input.indexOf(strFilter)>=0){
                         ++occurence;
                         console.log(occurence);//this worked fine
                    }   
                    if(index>=totalCount){
                        return occurence;
                    }
            });                             
        }); 
    });
}
```

This function only returns undefined or 0 but not the right value.

I read up a lot of articles on using Closures but just couldn't understand on breaking this problem up. Any suggestions or alternate ways of doing this would be helpful.

Comment: use `Promise.map` instead of `.each`

Answer (score 0):

So, finally the solution to this is chaining events based on promises by accommodating closures.

I start by creating an empty promise. From then on, I keep chaining events to the same promise overwriting in a loop. Finally, I wait once for all the promises to resolve for my actual work to begin!

```
this.getActualFilteredStatusCount = function(strFilter){
    return this.getTotalRows().then(function(count){
        var arrStatusTexts = [];
        //creating an empty promise
        var promiseKeeper = element.all(by.css(CommonElements.filterElement));
        return promiseKeeper.
            then(function(elmsArr){
                    for(idx=0;idx<elmsArr.length;idx++){
                        //create a self executing function
                        (function (idx) {
                            promiseKeeper=promiseKeeper.
                                then(function(){
                                    return elmsArr[idx].getText();
                                    }).
                                    then(function (statusText){
                                        //NOTE: the values here won't be in the same order everytime
                                        arrStatusTexts.push(statusText);
                                        });
                            }
                        )(idx);
                    }
                    //executes after all the promises above get resolved to return the occurence
                    return promiseKeeper.then(function(){
                            var occurence=0;
                            arrStatusTexts.forEach(function(el,index){
                                if(el.indexOf(strFilter)>=0){
                                    ++occurence;
                                }
                            });
                            return occurence;
                        });
                });
        });
    }
```

Not sure, if this is the best way! but this is all I got now

Answer (score 0):

I think it can even be cleaner / smaller. As far as I understand you have a table with a lot of text, and you just want to count how many times for example the string `foo bar` is found in the table?

`|hello foo       | hello bar   |
|goodbye foo bar | hello barry |
|foofoo bar      | bar foo     |`

It then depends on how the table is structured, but take for example you have a simple structure like `table > tr > td` and you want to check how many times the string `foo bar` is found in the `td`'s, then you can also do this

```
element.all(by.cssContainingText('table tr td', 'foo')).count()
  .then(function(amount){
    console.log('amount = ', amount);
  });
```

When you are using `async / await` it can be done in 1 line of code

```
const occurences = element.all(by.cssContainingText('table tr td', 'foo')).count();
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Yes your understanding is correct. But mine isn't a table but a div. The structure is somewhat like table-div ->row-div->the-div-i-need. I will try this simple one as well